# maven create doc from latex with centralized bib

Tags: maven, latex

I use latex to create my docs and it fits well into maven build so far.
Now I face the problem, that I want to centralize my bibliography.
I have the idea to put it into a separate project with styleguides and so on.
But how can I include that bib.bib file so that latex can reach it?

I had the idea to use the dependency plugin to unpack the dependency or at least the bib
and then copy it into the source directory with latex sources.
Maybe in phases pre-site and generate-resources.

What do you think about this? Any more elegant ideas?

Maybe in phases

Comment: Put the bib file in your texmf tree, then latex can find it no matter where you use it https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537161/36296

Comment: not in my case: i want to deliver.